# How to get PKCS8 privatekey from byte stream in C#

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, crypt

When retrieving the PKCS8 private key using below code, I get a `NullReferenceException`.

```
public ECPrivateKeyParameters GetMerchantPrivateKey(byte[] privateKeyBite)
{
    Asn1Sequence seq = (Asn1Sequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(privateKeyBite);
    ECPrivateKeyStructure pKey = ECPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(seq);
    AlgorithmIdentifier algId = new AlgorithmIdentifier(X9ObjectIdentifiers.IdECPublicKey, pKey.GetParameters());

    PrivateKeyInfo privInfo = new PrivateKeyInfo(algId, pKey.ToAsn1Object());

    return (ECPrivateKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privInfo);
}

[Fact]
public void GetMerchantPrivateKey__ShouldReturnPrivateKey__WhenPassPrivateKeyBytes()
{
    ApplePay applePay = new ApplePay(new MOBSHOPApplePayRequest());
    byte[] privateKey = Base64.Decode("MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgjyo3fzxT7j+CFxC7I4B5iVee2FUyn2vfOSjcgp2/g6qhRANCAARdoBFEtnuapXFKw4DYWsW0yV4bavpdWKszkefi19AhlIRE3WSNWSn25W5tZNFjMWtLISBmqANyufx2xP19oRvy");
    applePay.GetMerchantPrivateKey(privateKey);
}
```

The stack trace

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
BouncyCastle.Crypto
at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(PrivateKeyInfo keyInfo)
```

If I use `X9ObjectIdentifiers.IdDsa` I get this error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerSequence' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger'.
```

This Java example does work:

```
private PrivateKey inflatePrivateKey() throws Exception {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance( "EC" );
        return keyFactory.generatePrivate( new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec( _dataProvider.getPrivateKeyBytes() ) );
    }
```

Please check it and help me out in C#

Comment: Formatting improvements

Comment: Formatting improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using the following code, I believe it is equivalent to the Java version:

```
public static ECPrivateKeyParameters GetMerchantPrivateKey(byte[] privateKeyBite)
{
    var akp = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateKeyBite);
    return (ECPrivateKeyParameters)akp;
}
```

Comment: Please respond to this post, if you have the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810964/c-sharp-how-ro-get-x509-publickey-from-byte-stream